# Firebase Dynamic Links not working on iPhone with no SIM

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Going through the example located here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#set-up-firebase-and-the-dynamic-links-sdk

Things seem to work fine on iOS devices that don't support sim cards, like WiFi only iPads or iPod Touch. iPhones with sim cards also work. However, iPhones with no sim that still have internet via WiFi don't work. The screen just goes black and you get a ton of errors, noted below. If there are any options to get around this they would be greatly appreciated.

> Errors:
>   - Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: 
>   - Could not find specified service
>   - TIC TCP Conn Failed [2:0x283522b80]: 12:8 Err(-65554)
>   - HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])
>   - Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: dismiss = 1; is_weak_match = 1;

Comment: Please disregard. This is not related to the sim card. It turns out the devices that didn't work were older and ran iOS 12. That was the problem, not the sim card.